# Is there a list of facebook graphpaths one can use?

Tags: facebook

I'm playing around with the facebook api and finding it... extremely... frustrating. I suspect I'm not looking in the right spot, so apologies in advance.

All the resources I read seem to think that [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) is useful. I'm finding just the opposite (as much as i like "tables of contents" in books, online i find them poor. You cannot really "search" a table of content of that code or key word and instead have to open up every link, which is silly in 2013).

Is there some sort of resource - facebook approved or not - that lists all the "graphpaths" one can use?

I'm aware - somewhat - of the "me" graphpath, but what are the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to explore it.

There exits 2 different choices of starting path. Either /me or /{id}.

That ID can be personid, pageid or any facebookid.